# Import caffe giving Runtimewarning

Tags: python, boost, caffe, pycaffe

I installed caffe on my system following this link http://hanzratech.in/2015/07/27/installing-caffe-on-ubuntu.html . I was able to install it without any errors but when i did import caffe in the python terminal it is giving me this warning. Any reason as why is this happening and how it can be removed .

```
    import caffe


    /home/deep-learning/caffe/python/caffe/pycaffe.py:13: RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Net<float> > already registered; 
second conversion method ignored.
      from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
    /home/deep-learning/caffe/python/caffe/pycaffe.py:13: RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Blob<float> > already registered; second conversion method ignored.
      from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
    /home/deep-learning/caffe/python/caffe/pycaffe.py:13: RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Solver<float> > already registered; second conversion method ignored.
      from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
```

I am using a virtualbox in which i have installed caffe having Ubuntu14.04